# Delay Signing Assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

Why to use public key and private key separated from strong name in delay signing assembly.

how to use delay signing assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find something [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But please try to do some investigation yourself and post specific questions in the forum.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed signing is used when the author of the assembly does not have access to the private key that will be used to generate the signature